# CocoaPods adds a dependency not in Podfile: how to delete it?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have never add a file named `box` with podfile. but after `pod update`, it appearance and when I vim podfile want to delete it, it doesn't exist. How to delete it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pods can use other pods. So when you install them it install also inner pods. You can check your pods and see which one using it. Do not delete it.

Comment: My answer was already correct and accepted why did you unaccept it? @chaoxn

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of pods own dependencies in the `Podfile.lock` file. Open it and you'll see:

```
  - ReactiveCocoa (3.0.0):
    - ReactiveCocoa/UI (= 3.0.0)
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - ReactiveCocoa/Core (3.0.0):
    - ReactiveCocoa/no-arc
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - ReactiveCocoa/no-arc (3.0.0):
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - ReactiveCocoa/UI (3.0.0):
    - ReactiveCocoa/Core
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - Result (0.4.4):
    - Box (~> 1.2)
```

Which means that `ReactiveCocoa (3.0.0)` has a dependency on `Result (~> 0.4.1)`, and `Result (0.4.4)` has a dependency on `Box (~> 1.2)`.

Well, ReactiveCocoa **3.0.0** was in 2015. Nowadays in 2018, ReactiveCocoa is at version **7.1.0** and has a dependency on a newer version of `Result` which itself doesn't require `Box` anymore, so a `pod update` on the same Podfile will remove `Box`.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe owned by other pods, so don't try ro delete it.